# function to remove all observations that contain a "prohibited" value - R

Tags: r, database, function, dataframe

I have an large dataset looking like:

There are overall 43 different values for `PID`. I have identified `PID`s that need to be removed and summarized them in a vector:

I want to remove all observations (rows) from my data set that contain one of the PIDs from the vecotor `NullNK`. I have tried writing a function for it, but i get an error ( i have never written functiones before):

```
  for (i in length(NullNK)){
    SR_DynUeber_einfam <- SR_DynUeber_einfam [-which(SR_DynUeber_einfam$PID == NullNK(i)),]
  }
```

**How can i efficently remove the observations from my original data set that are containing PIDs from `NullNK` vector?**

**What is wrong with my function?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For basic operations like this, for loops are often not needed. This does what you are looking for:

```
SR_DynUeber_einfam[!SR_DynUeber_einfam$PID %in% NullNK,]
```

One mistake in your function is  NullNK(i). You should subset from a vector with NullNK[i] in R.
Hope this helps!

Comment: With your code the following is not needed, but in the original code there's another mistake, it should be `seq_len(NullNK)`, not `length(NullNK)`, I believe.

Comment: Agreed, always good for OP to know why his original code failed.